# Azure function triggering on folder creation as well as on blob create

Tags: azure, azure-functions

The Function should execute on blob write in any of the sub-folders and blob create. It will also be triggering on sub-folder creation.

The same function is working fine on our other environment. The only difference here is we are using the storage container with ADLS v2 and in the other environment we are using a general storage account.

Function Binding :

```json
"bindings": [{
  "type": "blobTrigger",
  "direction": "in",
  "name": "BlobTriggerBU",
  "path": "%bulkUploadContainer%/KP/{name}/{fileName}",
  "dataType": "binary",
  "connection": "AzureWebJobsDashboard"
}]
```

Comment: What exactly is your question here? What have you tried that _didn't_ work? Please refer to [ask].

Answer (score 0):

We have test in our local environment , By creating two functions app of .Net runtime with blob trigger function that monitor 2 different storage account types function app `logsgen2app` with Adls gen2 account ,function app  `revalidationrerouteapp` is with standard general purpose storage v1.

when we replace the storage account path in host.json with the below  to monitor a particular storage container the function is getting triggered
successfully.

```
 ## ADLS gen2 account ##
    "<containerName>/{name}/{fileName}"
    
    ## storage account V1 ##
    "<containerName>/{name}/{fileName}"
```

But when we replace the path that you have shared above the function invocation is not getting triggered and in  log stream function is  failing with the error message below

```
2021-10-25T13:17:36.240 [Error] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.BlobTrigger1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: '%bulkUploadContainer%' does not resolve to a value.
```

Here is the Sample screenshot of the error message  when we updated the path that you have shared.

[image]